# Javascript objects error

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial on Javascript objects on codecademy, the following code works and it display the output "sally' age is 39 while Holdens age is  16" however the editor says "opps, try again, false".
What is wrong with the code please?

```
  function Person( name,age ) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.species = "Homo Sapiens";
  }

  var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
  var holden =  new Person("Holden Caulfield", 16);
  console.log("sally' age is " + sally.age + " while Holdens age is  " + holden.age );
```

Comment: Which editor are you using? Putting this in jsFiddle and replacing `console.log` with `alert` works fine.

Comment: the codeacademy editor

Comment: while Holdens age is__ <- 2 spaces

Comment: codeacademy expects certain results. If the code works then it is likely you are not doing what you are being asked to do

Comment: I fooled around at codeacademy and I know that sometimes they ask you to do something in a very specific way. So maybe for example your variable name is different or you used object literal when they asked for dot notation. Have a good look at the instructions

Comment: This is what its asking me "Create a new object called sally using the Person constructor. Her name is "Sally Bowles" and she is 39. Create another object called holden. His name is "Holden Caulfield" and he is 16.

Edit the sentence printed out such that it includes the age of sally and holden respectively."

Comment: Use the hints then. This is not a valid SO question. All you have done is provide working code and asked what is wrong with it. To which the answer is nothing

Comment: Give a link and I'll try to help you...

Comment: [Maybe you should read this](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5163f2f3490e7e785d001db4)

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/spencer-sandbox/3/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific output expected by Codecademy.

Answer (score 2):

This is what they need for you to pass this tutorial:

```
function Person(name,age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.species = "Homo Sapiens";
}

var sally = new Person("Sally Bowles", 39);
var holden = new Person("Holden Caulfield", 16);
console.log("sally's species is " + sally.species + " and she is " + sally.age);
console.log("holden's species is " + holden.species + " and he is " + holden.age);
```

As I said in the comment to your question, codeacademy expects a specific result for you to pass. Sometimes it's not obvious. Whenever stuck you should check their forum since users share whenever they have problems like this in a specific lesson.

Comment: Thanks, i am new to programming and someone told me about the codeacademy website.

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that even if your code works it might not be what they asked you exactly, so check the hints and if you can't find a solution go to their forum. If the code I posted passed the lesson don't forget to accept the answer. Keep coding :)